# how to put twitter oauth token in header using ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I put oauth token for Twitter in header using Ajax and JQuery and how can I use header in ajax?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $tweet = $('#tweets');
    var $txt = $('#txt-area');

   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
         consumer_key: 'nAeMs0ys5YrTZSqA4xq9sGRuY',
         consumer_secret: 'LVEZpZwHCpZYGUyIeNV0XKWyPOJgtRar115qHQ28TPCktutanH',
         access_token: '874691145527373824-aIubP1xYLdI8KJ1dMm2n54TphyKZo47',
         access_token_secret: 'LS9v93OZqGC2kXt6nbkFoaWz2A4g6GZ3JPZGOFjUgdg4s'

      },
      success: function(data, text){
        var html = '<li class="tweet">TWEET</li>';
            $('#timeline').append(html.replace('TWEET', tweets(data.text)));
      },
      error: function(){ 
        alert("error loading");
      }
    }); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe like that:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader('access_token', token);
        request.setRequestHeader('access_token_secret', secretToken);
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: it can't work and show these errors:  jquery-3.2.1.js:3869 Uncaught ReferenceError: nAeMs0ys5YrTZSqA4xq9sGRuY is not defined
    at Object.beforeSend (main.js:12)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-3.2.1.js:9131)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:7)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.2.1.js:3583)
    at process (jquery-3.2.1.js:3651)